# PHP scripts won't execute/load on my web hosting server

Tags: php, .htaccess, webserver, cgi

Hi so my hosting provider screwed up my server and my website was unaccessible for a week. I messed around with the .htaccess and php.ini files and finally got my site to at least load again. Their tech ppl don't know how to do anything..

But I had a few php scripts that would fetch content from locations and add it to my wordpress site. They worked flawlessly before my host messed everything up! Now when I try calling them.. they'll take awhile to load, then just show a blank white page (its supposed to show a completed message and the content added).

I don't know much about .htaccess or php.ini files, but the last I heard from my host, both of those contained issues leading to my site not working at all.. They also messed up the error log reporting. So there are literally no hints to help trace where the problem is coming from.

If anyone has any idea how I can resolve this, I'd greatly appreciate it :) Thanks!

### PHP.ini - slightly changed from iPage's default:

(its over 3,000 lines long..)
Heres a link where I posted the code: http://codeshare.io/nqwrM

### .htaccess

Also linked to shared editor: http://codeshare.io/jDLz8

Comment: Moving hosts should be the first thing to do.

Comment: white screens on a php page = script died/puked/failed and all debugging options are turned OFF. turn on error_reporting, turn on display_errors, check logs, blah blah blah. no matter what you do, don't just sit there reloading a blank page hoping for something to change. GO LOOK WHY it's broken

Comment: Ugh. I was given free hosting for a year via iPage. I have no idea how to fix this :(